# Schema Compare Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

When I run a compare and update using Visual Studio 2012's Sql Schema Compare, I get "Could not drop object 'dbo.Countries' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
An error occurred while the batch was being executed."

Now I understand this error and I could manually fix this. However, shouldn't the Schema Compare when it creates the script account for that and drop[ the constraint before it attempts to drop the table?

Whats the point of this functionality if we just have to go in a fix what Visual Studio failed to account for? Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 0):

I found there to be a few default settings on the db compares which are there for protective purposes, but most can be overridden in the Schema Compare Options.

Have a look in there and see if this helps to resolve this for any future modifications you make.